# MEAN stack delete

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

Trying to add a delete button to my list of posts, that will delete the entry from the database, but only gets null when clicking the button.

My $scope

```
$scope.remove = function(post) {
  posts.remove(post);
}
```

Links to this function:

```
o.remove = function(post) {
    $http({ url: '/posts/' + post._id, 
            method: 'DELETE'                
    }).then(function(res) {
        // Deleted
        console.log(data);
        // Update list
        $http.get("/posts")
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(data);                
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

 };
```

Router:

```
router.delete('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {
        Post.remove({
            _id : req.params.id
        }, function(err, post) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            Post.find(function(err, post) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(post);
            });
        });
    });
```

Button

```
    <span ng-click="remove(post)">
      Delete
    </span>
```

My console.log writes null, and nothing gets deleted. Would appreciate all the help I can get, as I am very stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall have:

```
_id : req.params.post
```

Instead of:

```
_id : req.params.id
```

Because you have `:post` param in route:

```
router.delete('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {
```